# How to retry fetching after refresh token using redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I'm new in RxJS and I faced with need to retry fetching items to api if it responded with unauthorized error. I need to call refresh token endpoint and then retry fetching. How can I do it using epics from redux-observable? I guess it should looks like this code, but I'm not sure what to do in catchError block.

```
export const getItemsEpic = (action$) =>
action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_ITEMS'),
    switchMap(() => getItemsRequest()),
    map((response) => addItemsAction(response.data)),
    catchError(err => {
        ???
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a pipe like that

```js
export const getItemsEpic = (action$) =>
action$.pipe(
  ofType('FETCH_ITEMS'),
  switchMap(() => getItemsRequest()),
  map((response) => addItemsAction(response.data)),
  catchError(error => {
    // some logic how to refresh to token.
    return ajax('refreshtoken').pipe(switchMapTo(throwError(error)));
  ),
  retry(1), // allows only 1 failure.
);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! But I use React, it is possible to do the same? I use axios for requests.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad, sorry, in theory you can add the same pipe to the failed request.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. No refetching after token updates